# php shuffle access

Tags: php, ms-access

I’m using PHP with an Access database. This code works fine and displays 34 questions.  I would like to randomize the order the questions are displayed in but the `RAND()` function does not work with Access. I would like to shuffle the array but cannot get the syntax right. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$info2 = "SELECT * FROM CCNAATQuestions";
$rs2=odbc_exec($conn1, $info2);

while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs2)) {

    echo "<strong>" . $row["Question"] . "</strong>";

}
```

Comment: In Access the function is Rnd() not RAND().  See Dave's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM [tableName] ORDER BY rnd(INT(NOW*id)-NOW*id)
```

Try the above where id = your primary key column

Comment: @James You're welcome I'd appreciate you clicking the accepted answer if you're happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$rows = array();
while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs2)) {

$rows[]="<strong>" . $row["Question"] . "</strong>";

}

shuffle($rows);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$info2 = "SELECT * FROM CCNAATQuestions";
$rs2=odbc_exec($conn1, $info2);

$questions = array();

while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs2))
{
    $questions[] = $row;
}

shuffle($questions);

foreach ($questions as $row)
{
    echo "<strong>" . $row['Question'] . "</strong>";
}
```

Use shuffle from PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to fetch all rows before you can shuffle them:

```
$rows = array();
while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs2)) {
    $rows[]= $row;
}

shuffle($rows);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo "<strong>" . $row["Question"] . "</strong>";
}
```

You should have a look at  @Dave's solution to as it will use ACCESS feature. I unfortunately cannot test it as I have no Windows system at hand